# Maximum date row postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to find out a rows which have maximum date by product,

[image: click to see table]

I want to find out a maximum date of rows by product_id

[image: click here to see what i want]

I have tried a DISTINCT but can't succeed!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: `select * from product p where not exists (select * from product x where x.product_id = p.product_id and x.pdate > p.pdate);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from (
   SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by Product_ID order by date desc) r 
   FROM table 
) T
WHERE T.r=1
```

Comment: Great answer! its really helpful

Comment: welcome @RohanNayani if it helps you cam mark as answer

Answer (score 3):

One canonical way of doing this is to use a subquery to identify the records corresponding to the maximum dates for each product ID, and then restrict the original table via an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PRODUCT_ID, MAX(DATE) AS DATE
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID
) t2
    ON t1.PRODUCT_ID = t2.PRODUCT_ID AND
       t1.DATE       = t2.DATE
```

Another way to do this would be via a window function.